# Как получить адрес ячейки в которую будет добавлен элемент при push_back() c++

Tags: c++

У меня есть вектор с объектами пользовательского класса, в который мне нужно добавить элемент. В конструкторе класса B необходимо знать, куда будет помещен этот элемент (нужен адрес соответствующей ячейки b). Есть ли способ его получить?

```
     std::vector<A> a(2);
     std::vector<B> b;
     b.push_back(B(std::vector<A*> {&a[0], &a[1]}));
```

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете, что необходимо знать адрес свежесоздаваемого объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адрес, куда будет помещен объект `B` - это `this` в конструкторе. А чтобы он был именно адресом объекта, создаваемого в векторе, а не адресом временного объекта, следует использовать `emplace_back`:

```
::std::vector<B> b;
b.emplace_back(constructor_args);
```

Comment: "нужен адрес соответствующей ячейки b". Это же не `emplace`.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну я вроде по этому поводу написал

Comment: Я коммент написал до правки :) Ну и в вопросе всё же речь о `push_back`.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Вообще-то после. Или может это рассинхрон получился... А `push_back` и не нужен. От слова совсем.

Comment: Я не могу удалить свой принятый ответ.

Comment: @gbg а зачем удалять ответ? Описанную ТС задачу он решает.

Comment: Он ее решает очень криво. Не все решения имеют право на существование, тем более под зеленой галкой.

Comment: @gbg Можно указать, что то вариант для С++03. Мало ли, еще есть люди, сидящие в С++ Builder или VS 6.

Comment: @gbg, ваш ответ очевиден (и поэтому так и нужно делать), в отличии от данного. Подобный код будет совершенно непонятен многим программистам и поэтому ведет к  потенциально неработоспособным программам

Comment: @avp просто вы сишник, вам и ответ более близкий к сишному поведению кажется правильным. Про "потенциально неработоспособные программы" вообще не понятно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, просто я видел слишком много С++ программ, которые при модификации получали новые ошибки из-за непонимания новым программистом того, что наваял очарованный силой и губиной С++ его предшественник. Поверьте, первых намного больше чем вторых, которе еще и дороже стоят.

Comment: @avp ¿А это случаем не вы игнорировали видео за авторством Dan Saks?

Comment: @user7860670, очень может быть (тем более, что я вообще не люблю видео, предпочитаю текст)

Answer (score 4):

Вероятнее всего, тут [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710).

*Это решение для тех, кто еще не перешел на C++11 и выше. По поводу современного и более красивого решения смотрите* [другой ответ в этом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1273303/177993)

Нормально получить этот адрес нельзя, так как при вызове `push_back()` может произойти переаллокация массива и адрес станет негодным. Так что нужно как-то гарантировать, что переаллокации не будет - например, заранее сделать

```
reserve(a.size()+1); //или +N, если N известно заранее.
auto ofs = a.data()+a.size(); // искомый указатель
```